# std::string to a uint64_t

Tags: c++, boost, c++98

How do I convert a `std::string` to an `uint64_t`? I would also like the function to throw if the string does not contain a pure representation of an `uint64_t`. For example, conversions of these should throw:

```
"NO: 9889"
"9889L"
"9889U"
"1e+22"
```

or indicate by another means that they are not a pure representation. I am using C++98 and boost (including `boost::regex`).

Answer (score 9):

Use `boost::lexical_cast`. It will throw a `bad_lexical_cast` if the number can't be parsed or overflows.

If you ever switch to C++11, there's a new function in the standard for that which should be faster.

Comment: What is the C++11 equivalent? strtoll?

Answer (score 0):

A `for` with `isdigit()` followed by a `strtoll()` is always an option.

Perhaps not a one-liner, but a good function to write in your stringutils.cpp.